# Can parent class access variable of other parent class in Python?

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance

When reading the book Django Unleashed, I came across this code snippet. I was wondering why NewsLinkGetObjectMixin can access the class variable startup_slug_url_kwarg, which is define in another base class StartupContextMixin?

```
class NewsLinkGetObjectMixin():

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        startup_slug = self.kwargs.get(
            self.startup_slug_url_kwarg)
        newslink_slug = self.kwargs.get(
            self.slug_url_kwarg)
        return get_object_or_404(
            NewsLink,
            slug__iexact=newslink_slug,
            startup__slug__iexact=startup_slug)

class StartupContextMixin():
    startup_slug_url_kwarg = 'startup_slug'
    startup_context_object_name = 'startup'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        startup_slug = self.kwargs.get(
            self.startup_slug_url_kwarg)
        startup = get_object_or_404(
            Startup, slug__iexact=startup_slug)
        context = {
            self.startup_context_object_name:
                startup,
        }
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super().get_context_data(**context)

class NewsLinkCreate(NewsLinkGetObjectMixin, StartupContextMixin, CreateView):
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you inherit a class from several base classes, inherited class can access all attributes of the base classes.

`NewsLinkCreate` is inherited from both `NewsLinkGetObjectMixin` and `StartupContextMixin`. So, when you call method `get_object` on the `NewsLinkCreate` instance, it can access variables both from `NewsLinkGetObjectMixin` and `StartupContextMixin` because `NewsLinkCreate` is inherited from both classes. All attributes of both mixins are added to the class `NewsLinkCreate`.

Comment: It's worth it mentioning that this works because Python doesn't require declaring instance variables beforehand and therefore it doesn't know/check where the used instance variables are created/initialized. It only cares if the instance variables exist at runtime. This is forbidden in compiled languages such as Java or C++.